# Нaстройка .htaccess

Tags: файлы, php

Такая вот проблемка: заказал хостинг с поддержкой `php`. Заливаю файлы с форматом `.php` пишет `Internal Server Error`. Заливаю файлы с форматом `.html` - все работает. Гугл подсказал, что ошибка в `.htaccess`, типа нет директива `php`. Как исправить данную ошибку, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php  .php
```

добавить в htaccess. либо "Поздравляем! Вы стали обладателем хостинга Народ.Ру! Мы не поддерживаем Php!"

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, у меня такое бывает, когда нарушен синтаксис и вывод любых ошибок отключен.